# SQL Server XML parsing first node attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a XML column in database that may look like that ones:

```
<sql-connection-info name="myname" server="(local)\SQLEXPRESS" other-attribute="value" />

<oracle-connection-info name="othername" server="address" other-attribute="value" />
```

and so on. The names of nodes and attributes can be nearly anything. I need to iterate over the attribute/value pair on the first node. Every sample I have seen was for known node/attribute names.

When I tried to use

```
@xmlColumn.query("/@*")
```

I get this error

> XQuery [query()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported.

Is this possible in TSQL? If yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @xmlColumn xml = '<sql-connection-info name="myname" server="(local)\SQLEXPRESS" other-attribute="value" />'

select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') as Name,
       T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Value
from @xmlColumn.nodes('//@*') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
Name              Value
----------------  -------------------
name              myname
server            (local)\SQLEXPRESS
other-attribute   value
```

Comment: @Mikael is there a way to limit it?  I have similar XML, but it also has subnodes, and I only want the attributes from the top node. Thanks!

Comment: @mbourgon Sure, It is the double slash that make it include the sub nodes. Change to `nodes('/*/@*')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@xmlColumn.query("/node()[1]")
```

to get the first node of each entry. `node()` matches any element node.
From your post I do not understand if you want to have e. g. the `name` attribute of the first node of your entry. Then you would use:

```
@xmlColumn.query("/node()[1]/@name")
```

Comment: I need all attributes and get they names and values. I cannot use this @xmlColumn.query("/node()[1]/@name") because I don't know the names of attributes.

Comment: So could you do with teh first node itself, containing all attributes? That would be the result of my first proposal: @xmlColumn.query("/node()[1]")